# Simple Calculation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am performing a basic calculation using javascript and when I use this combination of number it won't calculate correctly:

```
alert((40071.13 + 6028.91) - 46100.04);
```

It should calculate to 0 but it doesn't.   All other number combinations work for me.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a rounding issue. Try this to round to 2 decimal places

```
var num = (40071.13 + 6028.91) - 46100.04;
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```

See it in action on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h1mxac6x/)